# sorting columns of Rcpp NumericMatrix for median calculations

Tags: r, rcpp

I've been testing Rcpp and RcppArmadillo for calculating summary stats on big matrices. This was a lot faster (5 or 10 times faster) than the base R colMeans or the the Armadillo on ~4million rows, 45 columns.

```
colMeansRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(X_="integer"), 
                            plugin='Rcpp',
                            body='
                            Rcpp::IntegerMatrix X = X_;
                            int ncol = X.ncol(); int nrow = X.nrow();                      
                            Rcpp::NumericVector out(ncol);
                            for(int col = 0; col < ncol; col++){
                              out[col]=Rcpp::sum(X(_, col));
                            }                             
                            return wrap(out/nrow);
                          ')
```

I really want to calculate the median and maybe other quantiles for plotting - and because it requires a sort its even more needy of C++ outsourcing. The armadillo seems a bit slow so I wanted to do an in place sort on code similar to above but I just cant get the syntax right... here is what I'm trying..

```
# OK I'm aware this floor(nrow/2) is not **absolutely** correct 
# I'm simplifying here
    colMedianRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(X_="integer"), 
                          plugin='Rcpp',
                          body='
                          Rcpp::IntegerMatrix X = clone(X_);
                          int ncol = X.ncol(); int nrow = X.nrow();                           
                          Rcpp::NumericVector out(ncol);
                          for(int col = 0; col < ncol; col++){
                          X(_,col)= std::sort((X_,col).begin, (X_,col).end));
                          out[col]=X(floor(nrow/2), col));
                          }
                        return wrap(out);
                        ')
```

Basically it's the line

```
X(_,col)= std::sort((X_,col).begin, (X_,col).end));
```

I don't know how to express "sort a column in place" with this mixture of Rcpp sugar and std C++. Sorry I can see what I'm doing is wrong but a hint on the right syntax would be lovely.

ps Am I right I need to do this clone() so I don't change the R object?

**EDIT**
I add the RcppArmadillo code and a benchmark comparison to address the answer/comment below. the benchmark was only on 50k rows for a quick reply but I recall it was similar with many more. I realise you are the Rcpp author.. so many thanks for your time!

The thought occurs that perhaps I'm doing something daft with the RcppArmadillo code to make it run so much slower than the base colMeans or Rcpp version?

```
colMeansRcppArmadillo <- cxxfunction(signature(X_="integer"), 
                                     plugin="RcppArmadillo",
                                      body='
                                      arma::mat X = Rcpp::as<arma::mat > (X_);
                                      arma::rowvec MD= arma::mean(X, 0);
                                      return wrap(MD);
                                    ')
```

And the benchmark is ...

```
(mb = microbenchmark(
+                     colMeans(fqSmallMatrix), 
+                     colMeansRcpp(fqSmallMatrix), 
+                     colMeansRcppArmadillo(fqSmallMatrix),
+                     times=50))
Unit: milliseconds
                                 expr       min       lq    median        uq        max neval
              colMeans(fqSmallMatrix) 10.620919 10.63289 10.640819 10.648882  10.907145    50
          colMeansRcpp(fqSmallMatrix)  2.649038  2.66832  2.676709  2.700839   2.841012    50
 colMeansRcppArmadillo(fqSmallMatrix) 25.687067 26.23488 33.168589 33.792489 113.832495    50
```

Comment: If you just want the median or some other quantile(s),
you do not have to sort the whole array:
[std::nth_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/)
works exactly like std::sort, 
but stops sorting the array when the desired element is in its final position.

Comment: Good comment (as usual) by Vincent -- and we do in fact have an Rcpp Gallery article on this:  http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sorting/

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of std::nth_element, and the Rcpp Gallery article is excellent on how to use STL to sort, partial_sort etc a vector....but I still don't know the syntax (if it exists) to sort a column of a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually showing RcppArmadillo code -- I have been quite happy with the performance of RcppArmadillo code where I needed row/col column subsetting.

You can instantiate Armadillo matrices via Rcpp just about as efficiently (no copy, re-using R object memory) so I would try that.

And you: you want `clone()` for a distinct copy, and I think you'd get that for free if you use the default RcppArmadillo ctor (rather than the more efficient two-step).

**Edit a few hours later**

You had left an open question about why your Armadillo was slow. In the meantime, Vincent solved the issue for you but here is a revisited, cleaner solution using your code as well as Vincent's.

Now how it instantiates the Armadillo matrix without copy -- so it is faster.  And it also avoids mixing integer and numeric matrices.  The code first:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector colMedianRcpp(NumericMatrix x) {
    int nrow = x.nrow();
    int ncol = x.ncol();
    int position = nrow / 2; // Euclidian division
    NumericVector out(ncol);
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) { 
        NumericVector y = x(_,j); // Copy column -- original will not be mod
        std::nth_element(y.begin(), y.begin() + position, y.end()); 
        out[j] = y[position];  
    }
    return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec colMeansRcppArmadillo(NumericMatrix x){
    arma::mat X = arma::mat(x.begin(), x.nrow(), x.ncol(), false); 
    return arma::mean(X, 0); 
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector colMeansRcpp(NumericMatrix X) {
    int ncol = X.ncol();
    int nrow = X.nrow(); 
    Rcpp::NumericVector out(ncol);
    for (int col = 0; col < ncol; col++){
        out[col]=Rcpp::sum(X(_, col)); 
    } 
    return wrap(out/nrow);
} 

/*** R
set.seed(42)
X <- matrix(rnorm(100*10), 100, 10)
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(colMeans(X), colMeansRcpp(X), colMeansRcppArmadillo(X),
                     colMedianRcpp(X), times=50)  
print(mb)
*/
```

And here is the result on my machine, with the concise Armadillo version about as fast as yours, and median a little slower as it has to do more work:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/stephen.cpp") 
R> set.seed(42)
R> X <- matrix(rnorm(100*10), 100, 10)
R> library(microbenchmark)
R> mb <- microbenchmark(colMeans(X), colMeansRcpp(X), colMeansRcppArmadillo(X),
+                      colMedianRcpp(X), times=50) 
R> print(mb)
Unit: microseconds
                     expr    min     lq  median     uq    max neval
              colMeans(X)  9.469 10.422 11.5810 12.421 30.597    50 
          colMeansRcpp(X)  3.922  4.281  4.5245  5.306 18.020    50 
 colMeansRcppArmadillo(X)  4.196  4.549  4.9295  5.927 11.159    50 
         colMedianRcpp(X) 15.615 16.291 16.7290 17.971 27.026    50 
R>
```

Comment: Hi. No forgive me i was unclear that wasn't the Armadillo code. I've edited the question to show this and the benchmark. Am I doing something daft to make the Armadillo code particularly slow? My point about clone was in this case I make a copy right- which i want if I am going ot sort it in place so as not to change the R object?

Comment: This is also really useful. As the Armadillo way is certainly more concise. And ~ as fast ... when you do it right. I have read through your excellent Rcpp gallery but obviously Ive not grasped some bits. Many thx.

Answer (score 5):

You can copy the column into a new vector with

```
NumericVector y = x(_,j);
```

Complete example:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
  NumericVector colMedianRcpp(NumericMatrix x) {
    int nrow = x.nrow();
    int ncol = x.ncol();
    int position = nrow / 2; // Euclidian division
    NumericVector out(ncol);
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
      NumericVector y = x(_,j); // Copy the column -- the original will not be modified
      std::nth_element(y.begin(), y.begin() + position, y.end());
      out[j] = y[position];
    }
    return out;
  }
')
x <- matrix( sample(1:12), 3, 4 )
x
colMedianRcpp(x)
x   # Unchanged
```

Comment: Thanks. Following your tip on nth_element this is what I did. I just got myself in a fankle thinking that since there was sugar to express columns and rows there maybe sugar to apply stl algorithms on them without copying. Obviously that would make it all too easy ;) .

Comment: @StephenHenderson You must make copies for that sort of things. Because `std::sort` of `std::nth_element` works in place, so if you don't use a copy, it will change the original data. You don't want that.